# List all chapter names and their descriptions from manpages

Tags: 14.04, command-line, manpage

How can we list all chapter names and their description in ubuntu manpages?

Comment: Ubuntu manual and manpages are different. Is your question about Ubuntu manual or manpages

Comment: @Anwar, It's all about manpages, mistakenly i wrote ubuntu manual,
Thank You for suggestion.

Comment: If you mean man *sections* (1 = executable commands, 2 = system calls etc.) you can find them listed in the manual page for the manual command itself (`man man`)